# Match on both HTTP_HOST and REQUEST_URI

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I want `www.foo.com/admin` to redirect to `admin.bar.com`, only when the HTTP Host is `www.foo.com`. I've tried combinations of the following but none seems to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://admin.bar.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: This code should be working as expected. Make sure htaccess are allowed (if you use that) and `mod_rewrite` is enabled in apache config. Also, make sure your rule is not ignored because of some other rules applied *before*